# Unknown build option '-p' in tsc typescript 3.5 when used with --build switch

Tags: typescript

If I run `tsc` with both `-p` amd `-b` in `tsc` in typescript 3.5, e.g

```
../../node_modules/.bin/tsc -b -p ./tsconfig.json
```

I get this error

> error TS5072: Unknown build option '-p'.

This worked in 3.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this situation; **you don't need the -p**. Since `--build mode` assembles multiple referenced projects, and those project references may be stored in multiple tsconfig files, you can [provide a list of tsconfig paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#build-mode-for-typescript) as arguments on any call that uses build mode. In this case, just `tsc -b ./tsconfig.json`.

While it is easy to think of -p as just a way to specify a tsconfig path, it actually explicitly specifies `--project mode`, which is [incompatible with build mode for performance reasons](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22997).

Comment: Such a wonderful answer - saved me so much time!